# $ionicHistory.clearCache() is not clearing current scope

Tags: ionic-framework

This is my code

```
$scope.moveToHome= function(){
   $ionicHistory.clearCache().then(function(){
      $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
        $state.go("app.home");
    });
}
```

In my app I have four views inside the ion-nav-view. From last view If click finish I want to move to the home page with new history. While calling moveToHome function I want to clear all the current history of the ionichistory. When i use  $ionicHistory.clearCache() it is clearing the all the history expect current scope. when i am coming again to the last view it showing last scope values only. If use $ionicHistory.history() It is clearing the history, but I can move to back page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app.js file you must have given entry for state, like following-

```
.state('login', {
    url: "/login",
    cache: false,
    templateUrl: "js/login/login.html",
    controller : ""
})
```

Using "cache" attribute as false, state controller will always reloaded i.e state will reload/refresh.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is an old issue, but for anyone that's coming 2017 or later I will explain what really happens and how to solve it:

The code of `$ionicHistory.clearCache()`:

```
clearCache: function(stateIds) { return $timeout(function() { 
$ionicNavViewDelegate._instances.forEach(function(instance) { 
instance.clearCache(stateIds); }); }); }
```

So, as you can see, it takes 1 parameter cllaed stateIds which is an array of stateId. Indeed i struggled to find out that stateId is nothing more than stateName.

So, let's go deeper. The code of `$ionicNavView.clearCache` which is used in the line above "instance.clearCache(stateIds)" is:

```
self.clearCache = function(stateIds) {
    var viewElements = $element.children();
    var viewElement, viewScope, x, l, y, eleIdentifier;

    for (x = 0, l = viewElements.length; x < l; x++) {
      viewElement = viewElements.eq(x);

      if (stateIds) {
        eleIdentifier = viewElement.data(DATA_ELE_IDENTIFIER);

        for (y = 0; y < stateIds.length; y++) {
          if (eleIdentifier === stateIds[y]) {
            $ionicViewSwitcher.destroyViewEle(viewElement);
          }
        }
        continue;
      }

      if (navViewAttr(viewElement) == VIEW_STATUS_CACHED) {
        $ionicViewSwitcher.destroyViewEle(viewElement);

      } else if (navViewAttr(viewElement) == VIEW_STATUS_ACTIVE) {
        viewScope = viewElement.scope();
        viewScope && viewScope.$broadcast('$ionicView.clearCache');
      }

    }
};
```

And as you can see in the code, this clearCache DOES NOT CLEAR ALL CACHES, instead, it destroy all cached views that matches a value in the `stateIds` array. If there's no parameter IT JUST DESTROY THE ACTUAL VIEW.

So the solution for this, using just the Ionic way is to call `$ionicHistory.clearCache()` with all your state names in an array as parameter.

E.g: **SOLUTION**

```
$ionicHistory.clearCache(['state1', 'state2', 'state3']).then(function(){$ionicHistory.clearHistory});
```

I cannot belive any Ionic developer didnt dug into the code before, or missed this simple datail.
I Hope someone takes advantage of this, even being so late.

**Just to make it crystal clear, i want to point out where the bug itself is (if we can call it bug), maybe can be handy for devs:

```
self.clearCache = function(stateIds){

[...]

     var viewElements = $element.children();

}
```

What the whole function does is basically:

Get all elements using JQLite
Loop the elements
Check if an element equals one in the StateIds array and destroy it; go to next element.
Check if element in the loop is cached or active, and in both true cases destroy it
I wont dig deeper into this but debugging it i could see that the elements gotten from var viewElements = $element.children(); is not an array of all your views content, not even the cached ones, intentionally or not it does not loop through out all your states to clear all those that matches 'ACTIVE' or 'CACHED'. If you want it to loop through ALL your states and destroy all cached views and data you need to explicity pass the stateIds array parameter.

Besides there's another strange behavior, because when i was debugging it i saw when the var viewElements array was filled up with 2 elements, and these 2 elements were from the same state, one resolved to 'CACHED' another resolver to 'ACTIVE', even resolving to the 2 types used in the if conditions the cache was not cleared at all.

I personally think that this is somekind wrong implemented or is wide used wrongly. The fact is that there's a lot of people cracking their heads on this and devs don't even give this simple explanation.